# how to make text a class object in python

Tags: python, myro, calico-project

this is my entire code:

```
from Graphics import *
import random
import time
from Myro import *
pt = Point(100,50)
pink = makeColor(200,100,150)
black = makeColor(0,0,0)
red = makeColor(255, 0, 0)
green = makeColor(0, 255, 0)
blue = makeColor(0, 0, 255)
purple = makeColor(255, 0, 255)
orange = makeColor(255, 153, 0)

win = Window("name", 1000, 500)
p1 = Point(0,0)
p2 = Point(200, 300)
p3 = Point(200,0)
d3 = Dot(p3)
p4 = Point(400, 300)
d4 = Dot(p4)
p5 = Point(400, 0)
p6 = Point(600, 300)
p7 = Point(600, 0)
p8 = Point(800,300)
p9 = Point(800,0)
p0 = Point(1000, 300)

win.setBackground(pink)
class Classes(object):
    WIDTH = 200
    HEIGHT = 300

    five = Rectangle(p9, p0)
    five.setOutline(black)
    five.setFill(orange)
    five.draw(win)
    four = Rectangle(p7, p8)
    four.setOutline(black)
    four.setFill(purple)
    four.draw(win)
    three = Rectangle(p5, p6)
    three.setOutline(black)
    three.setFill(blue)
    three.draw(win)
    two = Rectangle(p3, p4)
    two.setOutline(black)
    two.setFill(green)
    two.draw(win)
    one = Rectangle(p1, p2)
    one.setOutline(black)
    one.setFill(red)
    one.draw(win)

    '''def __init__(self,p,win):
        def numClasses(self):
            num = ask("How many classes do you have? Enter a number 1-5")
            int(num)
            if num == 1:


        def askOne(self):
            one = ask'''

'''class classOne(Classes):
    def __init__(self, win):
        Classes.__init__(self, win)
        self.appearance.setFill(red)
        self.appearance.setOutline(black)'''

        #self.append(win)
class classTwo(Classes):
    def __init__(self, win):
        Classes.__init__(self,win)
        self.appearance= Text(Point(100, 10), "Class 1")
        self.appearance.fontSize = 10
        self.appearance.setFill(black)
        self.appearance.draw(win)
        win.flip()
class classThree(Classes):
    def __init__(self, win):
        Classes.__init__(self,  win)
        self.appearance.setFill(blue)
        self.appearance.setOutline(black)
class classFour(Classes):
    def __init__(self,  win):
        Classes.__init__(self,  win)
        self.appearance.setFill(orange)
        self.appearance.setOutline(black)
class classFive(Classes):
    def __init__(self,  win):
        Classes.__init__(self, win)
        self.appearance.setFill(purple)
        self.appearance.setOutline(black)

t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
ti = Text(Point(win.getWidth()/2, 475), t)
ti.fontSize = 26
ti.setFill(black)
ti.draw(win)

title = Text(Point(win.getWidth()/2, 440), "Schedule for the week of:")
title.setFill(black)
title.fontSize = 20
title.draw(win)

classes = []
```

another thing, Window is a function in the version i'm using, i can't define it because it's predefined. it just opens up a separate window (1000 x 500) pixels where you can draw things. i just need to know how i get text to show up when it's entered under a class. it works for rectangles/points/shapes, but not text. i don't know why.

Comment: We have no clue what `Classes` is.

Comment: it's just an arbitrary parent class of classTwo. i can add it in if you need it.

Comment: ... How to put this..... We're smart, but we're not psychic. You haven't provided *nearly* enough information to give you an answer.

Comment: ok, so i need to know what else you need. i'm also not psychic

Comment: Start at the beginning, and when you get to the end, stop.

Comment: i just put everything else that is relevant in. the rest of the stuff is just text outside of the classes. it's a long code with a lot of comments for myself. i just need to know how to convert text to an object of a class.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense, but what is a Window?  Are you using some particular package?

Comment: i'm using calico. a window is similar to graphWin

Comment: We need to know how `Window` is defined. To the above code, add all of the `import` statements you use. It's also not clear what you mean by "an object of a class." I think you're misusing terms; that's part of what's confusing us. Don't just tell us; _show_ us what you mean by "object of a class."

Answer (score 1):

First - although you describe the classes (you tell Python what a classThree should look like and how it should work) you have never actually created one!

Second - if you draw the text, then the box, the box will overwrite the text and you won't see it.

Third - you're really badly misusing classes here. It looks like you're trying to do a school calendar, and make a separate Python class for each school period - taking what should be data and hard-wiring it as code. Instead, you should have a generic Period Python class and then make a separate instance per school period.

ie, instead of

```
a = FirstPeriod()
b = SecondPeriod()
c = ThirdPeriod()
```

you should be thinking in terms of

```
a = Period("First", blue, black)
b = Period("Second", orange, black)
c = Period("Third", purple, black)
```

Why?

- it makes what you are trying to accomplish more immediately obvious
- it reduces the amount of code (and thus the amount of debugging)
- it makes it much easier to make later changes

**Edit:** here is some heavily reorganized code - I do not have Calico installed, thus it is untested, but I hope it gives you the idea:

```
import Myro
from Graphics import Window, Point, Dot, Text, makeColor
import random
import time

Black  = makeColor(0,0,0)
White  = makeColor(255,255,255)
Red    = makeColor(255, 0, 0)
Green  = makeColor(0, 255, 0)
Blue   = makeColor(0, 0, 255)
Purple = makeColor(255, 0, 255)
Pink   = makeColor(200,100,150)
Orange = makeColor(255, 153, 0)
Grey   = makeColor(165, 165, 165)

Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday = range(5)

class Period(object):
    def __init__(self,
        className="<spare>",
        textColor=Black,
        bgColor=White,
        borderColor=Black,
        schedule=None
    ):
        self.name     = className
        self.text     = textColor
        self.bg       = bgColor
        self.border   = borderColor
        self.schedule = schedule or []

    def draw(self, win, rows, columns):
        for day,(start,length) in self.schedule:
            # draw background box
            box = Rectangle(
                Point(columns[day],  rows[start]),
                Point(columns[day+1],rows[start+length])
            )
            box.setFill(self.bg)
            box.setOutline(self.border)
            box.draw(win)
            # draw class name
            label = Text(Point(columns[day]+10,rows[start]+40), self.name)
            label.fontSize = 9
            label.setFill(self.text)
            label.draw(win)

def Week(object):
    def __init__(self, label, periods=None):
        self.label   = label
        self.periods = periods or []

    def draw(self, win, left, top, width, height):
        # how much room to reserve at the top
        label_space = 40

        # draw label at top
        label = Text(Point(Point(left+0.5*width, top+0.5*label_space)), self.label)
        label.fontSize = 20
        label.setFill(Black)
        label.draw(win)

        # figure out the grid for displaying the calendar boxes
        days = 5
        columns = [left + width*n/days for n in range(days+1)]
        periods = 5
        rows = [top + label_space + (height-label_space)*n/periods for n in range(periods+1)]

        # draw class periods based on the grid
        for p in self.periods:
            p.draw(win, rows, columns)

def main():
    win = Window("My window", 1000, 500)
    win.setBackground(Pink)

    week = Week("14 May 2012",
        [
            Period("Math",    bgColor=Red,   schedule=[(Monday,(0,1)), (Wednesday,(0,1)), (Friday,(0,1))]),
            Period("Geology", bgColor=Grey,  schedule=[(Monday,(1,1)), (Tuesday,(0,1)), (Thursday,(0,1))]),
            Period("English", bgColor=Blue,  schedule=[(Tuesday,(1,1)), (Wednesday,(3,1)), (Thursday,(1,1))]),
            Period("LUNCH",   bgColor=White, schedule=[(Monday,(2,1)), (Tuesday,(2,1)), (Wednesday,(2,1)), (Thursday,(2,1)), (Friday,(2,1))]),
            Period("Gym",     bgColor=Orange, schedule=[(Tuesday,(3,2)), (Thursday,(3,2))])
        ]
    )
    week.draw(win, 10, 10, 980, 290)
    # have to do something here to prevent closing immediately?

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should write text to the screen if you create an instance of the class.  So if you add this below your classes,

```
c2 = classTwo(win)
```

it should draw the objects for classTwo to the window.

Also, I was mistaken about the win.flip() part earlier.  It shouldn't be in the code.

Comment: calico, i don't know if that's what youre asking.. but that's what i'm using to interpret the code. i also might be missing the win.flip() command but i'm not sure where to put it/what it's for. also, i can put text into the window as long as it's not under a class. i don't know why

Comment: doesn't do it. i don't know what else to try

Comment: It might be helpful to try to write a new, really simple piece of code to test putting shapes into classes.